# Microsoft Sync Framework 2.1 Dynamic Sync between server and clients

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, frameworks, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I am looking for the best way to achieve the dynamic sync between server and clients. I have a central server and n-number of clients. I have designed a sync framework which will sync the data from and to between server and each client.

Here each client data is segregated by 2 filter columns. If I hard code these values for each client, then it will create one set of Sp' for each client (ex: selectchanges sp).

How can I achieve this dynamically? Please provide some sample code.

Comment: Can be closed under: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._

Answer (score 0):

if by dynamic, you meant dynamic filtering, it's not supported.

however, if you're concern is having one selectchanges SP for each client, you can use Filter templates so all the clients share the same SP but use different parameter values.

Comment: I just want to have one scope created at server and use that scope by all clients by providing specific filter values.Pls givbe me the sample code for this

Comment: look up filter template, it's in the docs complete with example

Comment: JuneT pls can you share the link of the doc

Comment: pls tell me how to use it.